# Cannot link tomcat-native library with Tomcat 9

Tags: java, tomcat, apr

I am trying to link tomcat native libraries with my tomcat 9 server in a CentOS machine. In order to do so, I have installed APR version v1.6.5, openssl v1.1.1 and then installed tomcat-native v1.2.19 with apr and openssl. I am passing the library path of libtomcatnative-1.so to tomcat through command line option -Djava.library.path=LIB_PATH_OF_TOMCAT_NATIVE. The library got loaded but when i use the native method SSL.version(), its throwing the following exception. What could be the reason?

```
""com.test.myservice.boot.ObjectStoreService"" ""start"" ""WARNING"" ""06-01-2019 10:55:33:108"" ""62"" ""Cannot load library"" ""java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.tomcat.jni.SSL.version()I
at org.apache.tomcat.jni.SSL.version(Native Method)
at org.apache.tomcat.jni.SSL.<clinit>(SSL.java:80)
at com.test.myservice.boot.ObjectStoreService.start(ObjectStoreService.java:59)
```

Comment: Please describe Connector? NIO/NIO2/APR? paste your server.xml part.